# Is 3-colouring NP-hard for 5-colourable graphs?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

Recently it was shown that it is NP-hard to find a 5-colouring of a 3-colourable graph.
More generally, it is NP-hard to distinguish $k$-colourable graphs from those that are not $(2k-1)$-colourable, for $k\ge 3$.

- J Bulín, A Krokhin, J Opršal. *Algebraic Approach to Promise Constraint Satisfaction*, STOC 2019. doi:[10.1145/3313276.3316300](https://doi.org/10.1145/3313276.3316300) ([preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.00970v3))

Turning the question around:

> Is deciding if a 5-colourable graph is 3-colourable NP-hard?

Comment: It is not the *decision* problem that is hard; every 3-colorable graph is also 5-colorable. "Distinguish" is not the same as "decide".

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and this holds even for structured graphs. Indeed, every planar graph is 5-colorable (in fact even 4-colorable by the [Four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)), but it is NP-complete to decide if a planar graph can be colored in 3 colors.